# Bootstrap button groups is not working properly inside the accordion

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion, buttongroup

Bootstrap button groups is not working properly inside the accordion.

```
<div class="panel-body">
      <label>Group Item #1 content</label>
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">Left</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rRZd9/)

Comment: You mean that they are not shown or they have a malfunction? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rRZd9/1/

Comment: Yes. The on/off state is not working

Answer (score 0):

I think this is about it

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
<div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">ON</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">OFF</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
<div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">ON</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">OFF</button>

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
<div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">ON</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">OFF</button>

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rRZd9/2/)